# Offline HTML file opening a popup in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've been working on producing a report in HTML format. The page is self contained (with images from data urls) because a single file is better handled by less technical users (e.g. sent by mail to someone else).

The report is composed by a base page with links that when clicked will open a different tab containing a set of images.

Excluding few minor annoying differences everything works as expected in all browser we want to support except in Internet Explorer (I tested with IE 9) when and only when the file is browsed from the local file system and not from a server.

When saving the file IE added the "mark of the web" automatically, and Javascript is enabled, but `window.open` raises an error.

I noticed also that the page doctype has been changed by IE in the saved version; originally was

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and now is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0035)http://raksy.dyndns.org/report.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Is there any way to allow a local HTML page to open a new tab in IE?

Comment: Did you ever find any resolution for this issue?